# How to move test store to new directory or domain?

Tags: magento2, domain, folder, directory

I am messing around with a test store so I can get my settings right and theme adjusted.  My plan is to move from Bigcommerce to Magento 2.0, so I want to have it all ready to go before I move and "flip the switch".

Any tips on how to easily move that installation from my test directory to a new folder or domain?

Comment: Are you using a version control system?  Do you have any custom modules or themes?  Do you wan to move all the test data, or just the products and website(s)?

Comment: It is just the stock install right now. Mainly I want the settings, products, categories, websites, etc. Can I create what I want and just transfer the entire contents of the magento directory to a different directory via ftp or will this. screw something up?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use a version control system like Git and commit the files to a repository (GitLab and BitBucket offer free private repository hosting if you don't want to pay for GitHub).

Then set the store up the way you want and export the database.  Then you can import the database to your production server and do a Git checkout on your code server.  Then run the `composer install` command to get all the dependencies and you should be good to go.

One thing to note is that if you transfer your database, you'll need to adjust the `core_config_data` table to replace the base URL values to be your new production domain.

Comment: Your note about "core_config_data" was exactly what I was searching for.